# ScrollView doesn't stretch enough

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have a `LinearLayout(horizontal)` inside a `ScrollView`. I'm trying to add `TextView`'s and `Button`'s inside `LinearLayout` with programmatically.

My code works without errors but with little glitch. My `ScrollView` only stretch for `TextView` not for `Button`'s. Sorry for the inadequate explanation, maybe screenshot helps: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWmLr.jpg).

`❒ Eve gir.` is a `Button` the rest is `TextView`.

How can I make `ScrollView` stretch and wrap my `Button`'s too. i tried set the `fillViewPort` but it did not work.

### `TextView` adding code:

```
 private fun createText(prTx: String, color: String) {

    val text = TextView(this)
    text.text = prTx
    text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    text.textSize = 18F
    text.setShadowLayer(5F,3F,2F,Color.BLACK)

    when (color) {
        "n" -> text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        "p" -> text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,182,193))
        "m" -> text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(182,207,255))
        "cm" -> text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(182, 242, 227))
        "olay" -> {
            text.setShadowLayer(5F,3F,2F,Color.rgb(100,0,166))
            text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(75,0,130))
        }
    }

    text.textAlignment = TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    text.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.llText)
    layout.addView(text)
}
```

### `Button` adding code

```
private fun createButton(prTx: String, clk: Int) { 
    val button = Button(this)
    button.text = prTx
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    button.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    button.textSize = 18F
    button.transformationMethod = null;
    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    button.setShadowLayer(10F,5F,5F, Color.BLACK)
    button.textAlignment = TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER

    button.setOnClickListener {
        when (clk) {         
        }
    }

    button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.llText)
    layout.addView(button)
}
```

### Layout's XML codes

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="#5B34515E"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivMutfak"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/clMiddle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clMiddle"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not `ScrollView`, it was `LinearLayout`. Problem solved when I deleted it `android:layout_margin's` of `LinearLayout. I still don't know why but this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`. Try this code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Sorry, my problem still continues

Comment: are you sure calling createButton method?

Comment: Yes, i'm setting onClick() method and it works normally. Just visual glitch.

Comment: Did you try remove this    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"?

Comment: It's covers the entire page. Looks a little bad [link](https://imgur.com/HhN2kwk)

Comment: Try again change it to app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap" instead of app:layout_constraintHeight_default

Comment: I did that but still covers the entire page. I tried keep app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap" and pp:layout_constraintHeight_default ="wrap", nothing has changed